# Altium multi-board project adding unwanted board names to system level nets

Tags: schematics, altium

I am working on my first multi-board project and I'm struggling to get the nets to be what I want.  I have a system with several copies of one board and then 4 other unique boards.  The multi board project is hypothetically useful for checking interface points between the cards but it is being super annoying with the nets.  The main power net is on every board, but it is labeled main_power_repeated_card_1, though not all nets that go to repeated_card_1 have that added to the end of the net.  I'd like to have the net just be main_power everywhere, so when I'm connecting main power on other-other card it doesn't look like it is connecting to just the power on repeated_card_1. [image]

Comment: Maybe you could use net tie? Another option might be to turn off the real checking on using two nuts on one wire and just labele them all main power

Comment: I don't think there are net labels for multi board schematics, they are only connector-connector types, and then the individual nets are inside those based off the individual board projects that get pulled in.